# unexpected behaviour of question mark after parentheses in RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, notepad++

**Why does the RegEx** `ni?` **differ from** `n(i)?` **?**

The question mark makes the preceding token optional.
But the preceding token is essentially the same: `i` and `(i)`
Therefore I don't understand, why I get different results.

*Matches for* `n(i)?`
[image: image1]

.
*Matches for* `ni?`
*(I highlighted the additional matches in green)*
[image: image2]

I expected both regular expressions to match all occurrences of `n` and `ni`.
But in the first image, some are missing. Why ?

The screenshots are from Notepad++
but I encountered the same behaviour in Javascript's RegEx engine.

PS:
Here is the sample text for you to copy/paste in case you try to reproduce my results:

> and in this way, it has significance. Jeremy Diamond
>   possible with the United States. So, I think there
>   potentially infrastructure development. Japan, for now
>   who on any given morning can see something in a paper

Comment: I see no difference in javascript. I tried both `'and in this way, it has significance. Jeremy Diamond possible with the United States. So, I think there potentially infrastructure development. Japan, for now who on any given morning can see something in a paper'.match(/ni?/g)` and `'and in this way, it has significance. Jeremy Diamond possible with the United States. So, I think there potentially infrastructure development. Japan, for now who on any given morning can see something in a paper'.match(/n(i)?/g)` and they return the same result

Comment: @slebetman it is in notepad++

Comment: @SagarV: He said it also happens in javascript. And I say it doesn't

Comment: Awww I didn't noticed that. Sorry for the comment

Comment: Notepad++ version 6.8.6 here: no difference between the marked positions for each re. I selected only these options: `Purge for each search`, `Wrap around` and `Regular expression`.

Comment: @Jan: Of course I cleared all marks before marking. Then I clicked on "mark all".

Comment: @slebetman : Yes, I encountered the same behaviour in Javascript's RegEx engine. But with a different test case (which also included the unexpected behaviour of the question mark after parentheses). I simplified both the RegExes and the sample text and played around with that in Notepad++ to better understand the problem. I just don't understand why `n(i)?` is not the same as `ni?`.

Comment: No repro on NPP v7.3.3 - anyway this looks like a bug, `ni?` and `n(i)?` should yield the same matches.

Comment: @LarsFischer: I have the same options selected as you. Notepad++ 7.2.2

Comment: May you post a test case for Javascript?

Comment: @slebetman : Thank you. I just tried and entered your code in the Firefox JS console and I can confirm that the output is indeed the same. I am at a loss however as to how to proceed to track down the error/problem.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: I just updated to Notepad++ 7.3.3 but I still get the same results as seen in the screenshots above. What OS are you running on? And have you tried with the same sample text I used ? Can you post screenshots ?

Comment: @horcrux : thanks for helping. Do you have good suggestions for a javascript greenhorn like me as to how to set up a not-obscure test case that would be useful for posting here ? My JS script and the included RegExes are a bit obscure. Did you mean I should post it "as is" or simplify it? (Incidentally, the test case I posted above is the result of my efforts to simplify the problem.)

Comment: Whay do you mean with "obscure"? Post the text where you say JS shows the buggy behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion above, I conclude that this has to be a bug in Notepad++, because it occurs in Notepad++ 7.2.2 and also after updating to Notepad++ 7.3.3

In case someone can alert the Notepad coders, you are very welcome.

I don't know what went wrong in my initial javascript test case, which I simplified to this StackOverflow question, but despite my initial impression the bug doesn't seem to appear in Javascript regex (as demonstrated above by @slebetman , whose results I could reproduce).

However, the bug in Notepad++ persists.